# FIFO dequeueing in python "AttributeError: Queue instance has no attribute 'front'?

Tags: python, fifo

I'm looking to make a functional (not necessarily optimally efficient, as I'm very new to programming) FIFO queue, and am having trouble with my dequeueing.

My code looks like this:

```
class QueueNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data) 

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.front = None
        self.rear = None
        self.size = 0

    def enqueue(self, item):
        newnode = QueueNode(item)
        newnode.next = None
        if self.size == 0:
            self.front = self.rear = newnode
        else:
            self.rear = newnode
            self.rear.next = newnode.next
        self.size = self.size+1

    def dequeue(self):
        dequeued = self.front.data
        del self.front
        self.size = self.size-1
        if self.size == 0:
            self.rear = None
        print self.front #for testing
```

if I do this, and dequeue an item, I get the error "AttributeError: Queue instance has no attribute 'front'." I guess my function doesn't properly assign the new front of the queue? I'm not sure how to fix it though.

I don't really want to start from scratch, so if there's a tweak to my code that would work, I'd prefer that—I'm not trying to minimize runtime so much as just get a feel for classes and things of that nature.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Show your real code, don't retype it.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to copy it correctly without all the formatting getting messed up, sorry.

Comment: Generally what I do is (1) get the code working (or if not exactly "working" then displaying the problem I want it to display), (2) highlight all the code in my text editor and indent by an extra four spaces, (3) copy and paste. Of course this relies on the fact that I'm using a text editor that can indent blocks of code and that can be set to indent by four spaces, but those are quite modest requirements for working with Python anyway :-)

Comment: Any particular reason not to use a deque? http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: the rudeness and patronization is not appreciated. everyone starts somewhere, and there are plenty of things at which I'm better than you. using the built-in collections wouldn't help me learn at all.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

```
del self.front
```

This removes ("deletes") the `front` attribute from `self`. Hence the error when you try to `print self.front` a few lines later. There's no such thing as `self.front` any more.

Comment: I understand that part, but I don't understand how I can go about changing it so that the self.front is altered to the next item in the queue and the old one is removed (and returned).

Comment: You probably want `self.front = self.front.next`, but I haven't tested that's correct. There's also a problem in `enqueue` with the line `self.rear.next = newnode.next`. This does nothing, because `self.rear` is `newnode` (set on the previous line). I think you need to replace those two lines with `self.rear.next = newnode` followed by `self.rear = newnode`.

Comment: you're a hero. that was my problem, I had tried `self.front = self.front.next` once before, but it didn't work because the nodes weren't being properly enqueued in the first place. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are also removing the attribute `self.front` then trying to access it again.

```
del self.front

print self.front #for testing # you are tying to use self.front but you removed it
```

You are missing `:` at the end of some of you functions.

```
def dequeue(self):  # <- missing that :
```

I'm not sure what your intent is here, but `self.front` is variable it has no attribute `data`

```
dequeued = self.front.data # remove the data
```

You are also missing a space between `def` and `__init__`

```
def__init__(self):
```

Comment: sorry, those errors were a result of me retyping my code with typos. I do understand that I'm removing the attribute, I just don't understand what I should do instead.

Comment: Why are you removing self.front ?